# Invalid data error when I take a picture from front camera

Tags: xcode, cgimage

I'm getting trouble with an image from front camera.
I resize and edit an image when a user takes a picture using CGBitmapContextCreate method.
It works perfectly when I take a picture using rear camera, but front camera said error message like below. 
 Error: CGBitmapContextCreate: invalid data bytes/row: should be at least 3412 for 8 integer bits/component, 3 components, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst.

I'm using these codes.

```
-(UIImage *) imageFlip:(UIImage *)img
{

CGSize size = img.size;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx,size.width,size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, -1, -1);
CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height),img.CGImage);
img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return img;
}
```

I tried normalize method from this [iPhone: Changing CGImageAlphaInfo of CGImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457116/iphone-changing-cgimagealphainfo-of-cgimage) but it still says same error.
Please help me.