# UIImage create bitmap context with png-8

Tags: ios, uiimage

Hi I am resizing my image using code from

http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/

```
- (UIImage *)resizedImage:(CGSize)newSize
                transform:(CGAffineTransform)transform
           drawTransposed:(BOOL)transpose
     interpolationQuality:(CGInterpolationQuality)quality {
    CGRect newRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height));
    CGRect transposedRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, newRect.size.height, newRect.size.width);
    CGImageRef imageRef = self.CGImage;

    CGBitmapInfo bitMapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef);

    // Build a context that's the same dimensions as the new size
    CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                                newRect.size.width,
                                                newRect.size.height,
                                                CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef),
                                                0,
                                                CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef),
                                                bitMapInfo);

    // Rotate and/or flip the image if required by its orientation
    CGContextConcatCTM(bitmap, transform);

    // Set the quality level to use when rescaling
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(bitmap, quality);

    // Draw into the context; this scales the image
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, transpose ? transposedRect : newRect, imageRef);

    // Get the resized image from the context and a UIImage
    CGImageRef newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];

    // Clean up
    CGContextRelease(bitmap);
    CGImageRelease(newImageRef);

    return newImage;
}
```

It is working as expected for normal images. However, it fails when I try to give it a png-8 image. I know it as a png-8 image from typing file image.png in the command line. 
The output is

```
image.png: PNG image data, 800 x 264, 8-bit colormap, non-interlaced
```

The error message in the console is colorspace not supported.

After some googling, I realized that "indexed color spaces are not supported for bitmap graphics contexts."

Following some advice, instead of using the original colorspace, I changed it to

```
colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
```

Now I am getting this new error:

```
CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination: 8 integer bits/component; 24 bits/pixel; 3-component color space; kCGImageAlphaNone; 2400 bytes/row.
```

FYI, my image is 800 px wide.

How can I resolve this issue? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the list of supported formats are here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-BCIBHHBB

And there is none with 24bits/pixel.

So I ended using the accepted solution here:
[iPhone: Changing CGImageAlphaInfo of CGImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457116/iphone-changing-cgimagealphainfo-of-cgimage/2484912#2484912)