# Save UIImage representation as PNG8, not PNG24?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, png

How can a `UIImage` be saved as **PNG8** (8-bit color mode) instead of PNG24 (24-bit color mode)?

The goal is to save space when dynamically saving many `UIWebView` screenshots that have *less than* 255 colors.

Right now I'm using `UIImagePNGRepresentation` after reducing the physical image size (Ref: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20791449/1938889)), but the images are still large.

Using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` with a quality < 1.f is *not* desired. Any other ideas?

Comment: please check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457116/iphone-changing-cgimagealphainfo-of-cgimage/2484912#2484912)

Comment: Did you find out how to do that?